# Equilibrium points of bounce/instanton solution after Wick's rotation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, equilibrium, quantum-tunneling, wick-rotation, instantons

In Coleman's paper [*Fate of the false vacuum: Semiclassical theory*](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.15.2929) while working out the exponential coefficient for tunneling probability through a potential barrier, he studies the problem with Wick's rotation $\tau=it$, getting to the Euclidean Lagrangian

$$L_E = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dq}{d\tau}\right)^2+V(q),\tag{2.14}$$

where clearly the potential is inverted. The potential as given in the paper is this

[image]

He then states that from conservation of energy formula

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dq}{d\tau}\right)^2-V=0.$$

i quote

> "By eq. (2.12)"-the conservation of energy-"the classical equilibrium point, $q_0$, can only be reached asymptotically, as $\tau$ goes to minus infinity"
>   $$\lim_{\tau\rightarrow-\infty}q = q_0.\tag{2.15}$$

- Q1. Why is this true? How you define infinity for a complex number?

Then, by translation invariance, he sets the time at which the particle reaches $\sigma$ as $\tau=0$ and that

$$\left.\frac{dq}{d\tau}\right|_{0}=0.$$

He goes on by saying that this condition

> "[...] also tells us that the motion of the particle for positive $\tau$ is just the time reversal of its motion for negative $\tau$; the particle simply bounces off $\sigma$ at $\tau=0$ and returns to $q_0$ at $\tau=+\infty$."

- Q2. Even this isn't very clear for me. Why should the condition for zero velocity at $\sigma$ imply that?

Is there something really basic that I'm missing? I'm not very competent in Wick's rotations and such and I have to understand every little bit of this paper for my bachelor's thesis.

Comment: $\tau$ is real. That's why we call it a *rotation* -- otherwise it would just be a change of symbol, i.e., merely notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Here we will work in the Euclidean$^1$ formulation, where Euclidean time $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$ is real. The potential is assumed to satisfy 
   $$ V(q_0)~=~0~=~V(\sigma) ,\tag{A} $$
   cf. OP's figure. The bounce solution satisfies the following boundary conditions (BCs)
   $$ \dot{q}(\tau_i)~=~0\quad \wedge\quad q(\tau_i)~=~q_0\quad \wedge\quad q(0)~=~\sigma,\tag{B} $$
   where $q\equiv |\vec{q}|$ and dot means differentiation wrt. $\tau$.
2. The potential is *minus* $V$. Energy is conserved (and equal to zero, since that's what it was in the beginning $\tau\!=\!\tau_i$). Therefore
   $$  \frac{1}{2} \dot{q}^2-V(q)~=~0
   \qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad 
   \dot{q}~=~\pm \sqrt{2V(q)} .\tag{C} $$
   Therefore we find that (minus) the initial time is 
   $$ -\tau_i~=~ \int_{q_0}^{\sigma}\frac{dq}{\sqrt{2V(q)}}.\tag{D} $$
3. Now since we assume that the potential is approximately quadratic
   $$V(q) ~\propto ~(q-q_0)^2  \quad\text{near}\quad q~\approx~ q_0\tag{E},$$
   cf. OP's figure, we see that the integrand (D) has a simple pole at the lower integration limit $q\!=\! q_0$, implying that the integral $\tau_i=-\infty$ cannot be finite.  This answers OP's first question$^1$.
4. From energy conservation we see that
   $$ \dot{q}(0)~=~0.\tag{F} $$
   By time reversal symmetry and uniqueness of solutions to the first-order ODE (C), it follows that the final time
   $$\tau_f~=~ \int_{q_0}^{\sigma}\frac{dq}{\sqrt{2V(q)}}\tag{G} $$
   is given by the very same formula (D). This answers OP's second question.
5. For more details, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219056/2451) related Phys.SE post and links therein.

--

$^1$ Concerning [Wick rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation), see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/500239/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything is clear

Comment: Correction to the answer (v3): _in the beginning_ should be _at the beginning._